# PHP MVC - How to deal with $_POST variables properly

Tags: php

I'm trying to figure out what is the best approach to manage $_POST variables into a MVC designed PHP app.

What I have at the moment, is an AJAX form. When this form is validate, it's passing through the router which select the good controller, and the good action. And in the action I check if have $_POST variables and I deal with them.

```
public function search(){
    if(isset($_POST['searchValue'])){
        //do some action with $_POST 
    }
}
```

But with this approach, if I want to use the same action without using $_POST variables, I can't.

So I was thinking to call a class before the router which will transform $_POST to parameters ( after validate them ), and give those params to the action.

```
public function search($datas){
    //do actions with $datas
}
```

So it makes the method usable with or without POST data.

But I don't have enough knowledge to understand if this solution will cause me trouble or not.

Or should I have 2 methods ?

post_search()

```
public function post_search(){
   if(isset($_POST['searchValue'])){
     //do some action with $_POST 
   }
}
```

and search()

```
public function search($datas){
     //do some action with $datas 
}
```

Comment: What does it mean: One for POST and one 'normal' ? Could your please explain?

Comment: You're right it's not really clear. I'll edit my question my anyway. What I wanted to say is : One method for POST as post_search() to manage if there is POST datas, and another method : search($params) if data are passed using method params.